# Custom stack data structure error in c++?

Tags: c++

I am implementing a custom stack class and I have a issue, my code shows this issue in a constructor part:

```
error: qualified reference to 'Stack' is a constructor name rather than a type in this context
Stack::Stack(int size)
       ^
lab5.cpp:182:18: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
Stack::Stack(int size)
```

I am not sure where the mistake is:

```
class Stack
{
    private:
    char *arr;
    int t;
    enum {stack_size=100};
    int capacity;

public:
    Stack(int size = stack_size);       
    ~Stack();                   
    void push(char) ;
    char pop() ;
    char top();
    int size();
    bool empty();
    //bool isFull();
};

Stack::Stack(int size)
{
    arr = new int[size];
    capacity = size;
    t = -1;
}
```

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: `arr = new int[size];` -> `arr = new char[size];`

Comment: better if you declare you constructor with `explicit`. as @jabberwocky told the issue.

Comment: thanks but it still shows: qualified reference to 'Stack' is a constructor name rather than a type in this context

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/4ba4MP it is working here.

Comment: There must be something you're not telling us. The code snippet in your questions [compiles fine](https://www.godbolt.org/z/MG1GKh) once the modification I've suggested in my previous comment has been done. What is your platform/compiler/ide/operating system/versions etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the type of `arr` from `char*` to `int*`, then the code can be built with *Visual Studio 2019*.

```
class Stack {
private:
    int* arr;
    int t;
    enum { stack_size = 100 };
    int capacity;

public:
    Stack(int size = stack_size);

    ~Stack(){};

    void push(char){};

    char pop() {
        return '0';
    };

    char top() {
        return '0';
    };

    int size() {
        return 0;
    };

    bool empty() {
        return false;
    };
    //bool isFull();
};

Stack::Stack(int size) {
    arr = new int[size];
    capacity = size;
    t = -1;
}
```